# Statistics and Probability, finding unbiased estimates of mean and variance given sigma x and sigma (x^2)

Tags: probability, statistics

The random variable $X$ is normally distributed with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$. A random sample of $20$ observations on $X$ gave the following results $\sum_i X_i = 280, \sum_i X_i^2 = 3977.57$. Find the unbiased estimates of the mean and the variance

Finding the unbiased mean is fine, it is simply $\frac{280}{20}$, which is $14$. I have been given the answer sheet and have found that the variance is, however, $\frac{3977.57}{19} - \frac{280^2}{380}$. Now I could figure out the first bit with $\sum_i \frac{X_i^2}{n-1}$, but where the $380$ comes from is beyond me. Can anyone explain where the $380$ comes from and what it is?

Comment: What is Ex? If you say that the unbiased estimate of the mean is $280/20$, then Ex is the sum of observations, right? And Ex^2 is the sum of the observation squared, is that right? Please, make your question clearer.

Comment: Just noticed that 380 is 20^2 - 20. Am I correct in that this is what it is derived from?

Comment: @ V.C, Ex should have been Sigma X, or the sum of X, etc. My bad! You are quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unbiased estimator of the variance is given by
$$
\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-\frac n{n-1}\bar y^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-\frac 1{n^2-n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\biggr)^2.
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2=\frac1{19}\cdot 3977.57-\frac1{20^2-20}\cdot 280^2=\frac1{19}\cdot 3977.57-\frac1{380}\cdot 280^2.
$$